# How to fix the label displacement in a bar plot?

Tags: matplotlib, label, seaborn, bar-chart

this is my code:

```
`# Create a bar plot using seaborn
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
sns.barplot(x="Month", y="Valor", hue="Year", data=monthly_precipitation, palette="Paired")

# Customize the plot
plt.title("Precipitación total mensual - Estación  Santa Elena [27010810] IDEAM")
plt.xlabel("Mes")
plt.ylabel("Precipitación [mm]")
plt.legend(title="Año", bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')

# Define numeric ticks corresponding to months
x_ticks = range(1, 13)
# Set month labels
month_names = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"]
# Set custom x-axis ticks and labels
plt.xticks(x_ticks, month_names)

# Show the plot
plt.show()`
```

But the plot resulting has a displacement on the x label, so it looks like "ENERO" doesn't have label, and "DICIEMBRE" doesn't have data.
[plotresult_xlabeldisplaced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIX1H.png)

I also tried using "plt.xticks(range(1, 13), month_names)", also I tried to Manually set x-axis ticks for each month for each year.

```
`# Manually set x-axis ticks for each month for each year
num_years = len(monthly_precipitation["Year"].unique())
ticks_per_year = 12
tick_positions = [ticks_per_year * i + j + 0.5 for i in range(num_years) for j in range(12)]

# Change x-axis labels to month names
month_names = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"]
plt.xticks(tick_positions, month_names * num_years)`
```

But the result is the same: label displaced.

as you can see in the image, I expect the x label to be one position to the left so the label matches the data.

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!!

Comment: In Python, indexing starts at zero. Also for the tick labels. So, you need `x_ticks = range(0, 12)` (which is the same as `x_ticks = range(12)`). Even when the months are numbers 1 to 12, or any other numbering (or strings), the bars are always labeled starting from zero.